# How to exit parent / ancestor frame on click of new frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I created 4 different JFrames each has an exit button.

- On click of the exit button there is new frame which asks - *Are you sure ?*. There are the buttons: Yes & No
- On click of yes I want to close current as well as the frame from which the call is generated.

To close current frame I use

```
closeOptionPane.this.dispose();
```

But how can I close the ancestor or parent frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on click of Exit button there is new frame which asks - Are you sure ?

This should NOT be a JFrame. This should be a JOptionPane. A JOptionPane will close automatically when you click on its buttons.

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples.

> each has exit button,

So then you must be adding an ActionListener to the button. So the basic code in the Action listener would be something like:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...);

if(result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
    JButton button = (JButton)event.getSource();
    Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( button );
    window.dispose();
}
```